# Swiper JS / React - is it possible to change the current slide depending on some variable

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to bind a slider to a timer so that the slides automatically change depending on the **num** parameter. For example **num** > 0 && **num** < 1000 will automatically change to the first slide. I tried to do it with **swiper.slideTo** but the method doesn't work without page reload. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Here is some code from my-app:**

I managed to change the **num** value through the slider

```
  const getIndex = (index) => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        setNum(-2000);
        break;
      case 1:
        setNum(-1000);
        break;
      case 2:
        setNum(500);
        break;
      case 3:
        setNum(2000);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

with **onSlideChange** method

```
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={1}
          slidesPerView={1}
          onSlideChange={(e) => getIndex(e.realIndex)}
          navigation
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          {arr.map((item, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide style={{ backgroundColor: item }} key={index}>
              <h1>Slide {index + 1}</h1>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
```

now i am trying to automatically change slide based on **num** variable

Comment: Please do try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying. It's rather impossible to help debug code if we can't see what it's doing.

Comment: some code from app , is it enough? or u need complete app code?

Answer (score 3):

managed how to do it with **useRef** and **useEffect** hooks

```
const sliderRef = useRef();
const [myIndex, setMyIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (num >= -2000 && num < -1000 && myIndex !== 0) {
      setMyIndex(0);
    }
    if (num >= -1000 && num < 500 && myIndex !== 1) {
      setMyIndex(1);
    }
    if (num >= 500 && num < 2000 && myIndex !== 2) {
      setMyIndex(2);
    }
    if (num >= 2000 && myIndex !== 3) {
      setMyIndex(3);
    }
  }, [num, myIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    sliderRef.current.swiper.slideTo(myIndex);
  }, [myIndex]);
```

```
<Swiper
          ref={sliderRef}
          spaceBetween={1}
          slidesPerView={1}
          onSlideChange={(e) => getIndex(e.realIndex)}
          navigation
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          {arr.map((item, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide style={{ backgroundColor: item }} key={index}>
              <h1>Slide {index + 1}</h1>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
 </Swiper>
```

Comment: Thx to user: dhruveonmars